# How do i change the distance as game accelerates?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to make a game like [Canabalt](http://adamatomic.com/canabalt/) with JAVA using LibGDX, in the game the background accelerates right to left while the player stays on the same position.The distance increases by 1 every second and the speed accelerates by 0.15f like this:

```
public void update(float delta){
    timeState += delta;
    speed += 0.15f;

    if(timeState >= 1){
        timeState = 0f;
        distance += 1;
    }

    if (speed > MAX_SPEED) speed = MAX_SPEED;

}
```

But i don't want the distance to be constant, i want it to change relative to the speed. So as the speed increases the distance starts to increment faster too. And when the max speed is reached the distance increment should also be constant. How can i archieve that?

Comment: `distance += speed`?

Comment: `speed += ACCELERATION * delta` `distance += speed * delta`

Comment: The initial speed is 1000 so the distance starts at 1000 too i want the distance to start at 0.

Comment: Thanks it worked now i did this: `speed += ACCELERATION * delta;`
 `distance += (speed - INITIAL_SPEED) * delta;`                                       `if(speed > MAX_SPEED) speed = MAX_SPEED;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is probably more straightforward to have `distance` represent the true distance covered, something like:

```
public void update(float delta){
    distance += speed * delta;  //  distance = speed * time
    speed += 0.15f;

    if (speed > MAX_SPEED) speed = MAX_SPEED;
}
```

That way your variables actually reflect what is happening in the game rather than having to use the fudgy timestate workaround.

The only difference here is that `distance` will now need be a float - casting this to an int (like `(int)distance`) will truncate it and leave it with the integer value you seem to want from your above code.

Comment: @HarryBanda Just saw you solved  this in the  comments, maybe accept an answer to mark it as  resolved - you can always write and accept your own answer

Comment: My speed does not start at 0, but at an initial speed of 1000. if i write `distance += speed * delta` the distance starts counting at 1000 instead of zero. In the game the distance is the score, i don't want very large number for that.

Comment: No, your delta will presumably be less than 1. If you want your distance to be a scaled version of the 'real' distance, just add the scaling multiple to the sum eg distance += 0.1 * speed * delta

Answer (score 0):

Using maths function Logarithm should do the trick, as your speed will reach a limit and distance will also use the same path, the effect will be smoothier.

Comment: How can i go about doing that?